Print Doc from Spreadsheets to PDF
I print a table as a PDF using the following script (1 page = offer = TEST1):
function PDF_TEST() {
  // Déclaration des variables et constantes
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('TEST');
  var sheetName = "TEST";
  var folderID = "*** FOLDER ID ***";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var dateiname = feuille.getRange('K1').getValue();
  var pdfName = dateiname + ".pdf";

  // Pièce jointe -- this part is stealed from envoiMail() function
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", classeur.getId());
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    + '&size=A4'
    + '&top_margin=0.00'
    + '&left_margin=0.00'
    + '&right_margin=0.00'
    + '&bottom_margin=0.00'
    + '&portrait=true'
    + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
    + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'
    + '&fzr=false' + '&gid=';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var pdfMarge = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + feuille.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  }).getBlob().setName(pdfName);

  folder.createFile(pdfMarge);

 
}

However, after the first page (from Spreadsheets = Test1) I have to attach another text document from Google Docs (Page 2 = Terms and Conditions = Test2) to the PDF from Spreadsheets (Test 1). How do I get that?
Can you print the DOC document as a PDF directly from the Spreadsheets script?
I don't have an idea
